# Sans serif symbols in XeLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, xetex, symbols, fontspec

I want to introduce a family of sans serif symbols using the `TeX Gyre Heros` italic font.
I have only managed to use the upright font, How do I achieve this with the italic font?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmathsf{TeX Gyre Heros}

\newcommand{\sfmu}{\mathsf{μ}}

\begin{document}

\[
\sfmu : X \to Y
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: For reasons that are quite difficult to understand, Unicode reserves code points for Greek sans serif boldface italic, but not for medium weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search "texgyrehero" in your computer and you can get a font `texgyreheros-italic.otf`, set `mathsf` to it like

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmathsf{texgyreheros-italic.otf}

\newcommand{\sfmu}{\mathsf{μ}}

\begin{document}

\[
\sfmu : X \to Y
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Another solution: Use `unicode-math` package

First you can refer to [Greek sans serif math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321418/greek-sans-serif-math) .

And you can try another opentype font which support "Math" script, like "Fira Math". Here are two examples:

1. If you want to use sans serif `\mu` in total paper, you can use

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mitmu]{FiraMath-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

\[
    \mitmu : X \to Y,
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: \mitmu]

2. As you said, you can declare a `sfit` family, here I call it `fira`, you can use

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfontface\fira{FiraMath-Regular.otf}


\begin{document}

\[
    \fira{\mupmu, \mitmu} : X \to Y,
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: \fira]

3. If you insist on using `TeX Gyre Heros`, you can use

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfontface\sfit{texgyreheros-italic.otf}
\setmathfontface\sfup{texgyreheros-regular.otf}

\begin{document}

\[
    \sfit{\mupmu}, \sfup{\mupmu} : X \to Y,
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: \sfit]

Because TeX Gyre Heros doesn't contain "Math" script, so we can't use `\sfit{\mitmu}` to get a italic `\mu`.

In those examples, `\mupmu` is a command declared by `unicode-math`, which means `m(math)up(upright)mu(μ)`, so you can easily guess what `\mitmu` means.

Comment: I just found out that ```\setmathsf{TeX Gyre Heros Italic}``` will work, but then I can't use the upright sans serif font. I think what I really want is a way to define a new ```\mathsfit``` family.

Comment: There is one thing you have to know: TeX Gyre Heros doesn't contain "Math" script, it mean you'd better not use it in math mode. If you want a sans serif math font, you can use `Fira Math`, a opentype sans serif math font.